# Can you explain this piece of code?

Tags: c

Rest is ok but, I did not understand what is happening in this part:

for (x = 15; **x % i ? ++i : ++k**, i < x; x--, i++)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int x, i = 2, k = 1;
    for (x = 15; x % i ? ++i : ++k, i < x; x--, i++) {
        x = -k + i;
        i++;
        printf("X = %d, I = %d, K = %d\n", x, i, k);
    }

    switch (x) {
      case 2: printf("Display 2.\n");
      case 5: printf("Display 5.\n");
      case 0: printf("Display 0.\n");
        break;
      default: printf("Display default\n");
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `x%i ? ++i : ++k` increases i for uneven x and k for even x. `i<x` is the termination condition. I think the comma operator only returns the last value, so the first statement is only there for the side effects.

Comment: @kamikaze Broadly correct. But it's a bit more complicated than that because `i` changes and hence it's not a simple even/odd condition.

Comment: Read about conditionnal expressions. And never write code like this, it's pretty unreadable.

Comment: @kaylum I haven't really looked at the context. We're looking at an ugly hack after all. EDIT: Oh crap, now I see it. Ouch.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions/253896#comment17104_253896

Comment: Nobody, except possibly yourself and your prof/TA, cares what is happening.  It's typical madcademia code and would never be seen outside an assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, a for loop has the following structure:

```
for (part1; part2; part3) {
    ....
}
```

- **Part 1** is a statement which is executed once, before the loop starts.
- **Part 2** is the condition you check at each iteration.
- **Part 3** is a statement which is executed at the end of each iteration.

So here, Part 2 is `x%i ? ++i : ++k, i<x ;` which checks two conditions :

- `x%i ? ++i : ++k`. This is a short way to write an `if-else`statement. It can be written as:

  ```
  if (x % i)    //equivalent to : if ((x%i) == 1)
      ++i;
  else
      ++k;
  ```

This means that `i` is incremented if `x` can be divided by `i` and k is incremented if it cannot.

- `i < x` is an obvious comparison.

Answer (score 5):

This is idiotic code, but to understand it you just have to break it down:

```
for(x=15 ;                 // init x = 15
    x%i ? ++i : ++k, i<x ; // if x is not a multiple of i then increment i, 
                           // otherwise increment k, 
                           // and then exit loop if i >= x
    x--, i++)              // decrement x, increment i
```

Comment: @LPs: thanks - fixed !

Answer (score 1):

This is composition of c++ ternary operator, comma operator and increment operator. It's equivalent function will

```
bool f(int x, int &i, int&k)
{
   if (x%i != 0)
   {
      ++i;
      return i != 0;
   }
   else
   {
      ++k;
      return i < x;
   }
}
```

And the `for` will be now

```
for(x=15 ; f(x, i, k); x--, i++)
{
    x=-k+i;
    i++;
    printf("X = %d, I = %d, K = %d\n", x, i, k);
}
```

Comment: `This is composition of c++ ternary operator` but not of `C`?

Answer (score 0):

This is the **Ternary Operator** ([read about it on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:))

```
conditionalStatement ? "returnsThisWhenStatementIsTrue" : "returnsThisWhenStatementIsFalse"
```

It returns ++i when "x % i" is truthy, and returns ++k otherwise.

That's all. ; )